# Java: adding attachment to the mail client launched using getDesktop().mail(URI)

Tags: java, email-attachments

In Java, how to launch the mail client along with the given file as its attachment - particularly using the method `Desktop.getDesktop().mail(URI)`

I am using Windows 7 and want to launch MS Outlook.

Comment: I am using Win7 and want to launch MS Outlook. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it is unfortunatly not possible to specify any attachment using `Desktop.mail(URI)`.
I've tried AlexR suggestion. It doesn't work if the file is too big because of the restriction of the number of characters in the URI.

However, it is still possible using [JMAPI](https://github.com/briandealwis/jmapi), though it only works on x86 platforms.

The ultimate way to make it work is using the [JavaMail API](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/index.html), but it forces you to create your own GUI and to set the SMTP server configuration.. which is not pretty user-friendly.

If anyone as other suggestions, i'd be glad to know them.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good question.

Indeed the `URI` that sent as a parameter to method `desktop.mail(URI)` allows setting to, cc, bcc, subject, body and does not allow setting attachments. (see http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2368.txt)

However attachments are actually specially formatted fragments of email body. Please read this for more details: http://techhelp.santovec.us/decode.htm.
This means that you can encode your binary attachment using Base64 and create email body that already contains the attachment of any generic file. I personally have not tried this but I  believe it must work. Good luck.

Comment: See `DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(byte[])` for a J2SE method to do the conversion.

Comment: Has anyone used this? It will be very helpful if you can give the link for some sample code.. :)